# Upgrade Rapid-Sql Client to work with Sybase 15

Tags: sybase, driver, rapidsql

I'm attempting to run queries on a Sybase15 database via Rapid Sql. I'm getting error messages such as

```
-- Number (103) Severity (15) State (207) Server (serverName) The identifier that starts with '[xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxx' is too long. Maximum length is 28
```

which I believe it because the Rapid Sql Client is using Sybase 12.5 properties.

I have updated the Sybase Client version but now Rapid Sql complains with the following:

Can not load Open Client, please verify that libsybct.dll/libct.dll and libsybcs.dll/libcs.dll are in your path. Please make sure your version of Open Client library is 11.1.1 or greater. If you are using an upgraded copy of Open Client 11.1.1, please install a full copy

My path includes C:\Program Files\Sybase.15\OCS-15_0\dll which is where the dlls are stored and my version of Open Client is 15.0 as can be seen below:

C:>isql -v
Sybase CTISQL Utility/15.0/P-EBF12974 ESD #1/PC Intel/BUILD1500-002/OPT/Thu Sep
29 14:51:28 2005

Any ideas?

Comment: This is due to the fact that the path variable on the users machine is too long for the Sybase driver to get to the needed DLL's and EXE's to function properly.

Bring the sybase15 folders to the front of the path and Rapid Sql should work.

Comment: I am getting same error, ecatly what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error the reason why was because my sql10 folder was missing some files. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RSQL871 and look for the sybinit.err file. Open that file in a text editor and it will tell you what files are missing or what files it cannot read. It tells you one at a time so if you find the file that you are missing, and put it in the sql10 folder then start rapid sql again and try to connect it might give you the same error message again. This just means there is another missing file. if you look at the sybinit.err file again the file name of the missing file would have changed so you need to keep doing this until there are no more errors.